# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ea' of null

Tags: dictionary, angular

I am using angular2 with typescript and angular2-google-maps,

The following is the dependency found in the package.json file:

"angular2-google-maps": "^0.12.0"

It almost running quite well without problem, but I am facing this exception when navigating through the map:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ea' of null

[image]

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

We can't really diagnose code you haven't posted.  However, I can interpret the error message somewhat.  Somewhere within the code, there is a reference to an object (let's call it **obj**) and its property (a.k.a. attribute or field) **ea**.  For instance,

```
x = obj.ea
```

When execution got to whatever statement is making the reference, **obj** was **null**.  Null objects are pretty boring; among other things, they don't have properties.  :-)

You need to read the stack trace to find where the error occurred, trace the value of the object, and find out why it's **null** when it should have a more useful value.

Comment: To understand more clearly my case, please try the following url: http://plnkr.co/edit/YX7W20?p=preview  
open the console and navigate the map there, you will get that error. 
Do you have any idea why that happened? 
I think it is from the library angular2-google-maps.

Comment: I don't get the error.  I've switched views, slid the map to different areas, dragged point "A" down to Salzburg, and peeked around the interior of some home.

Comment: Try to navigate through it fast without touching any marker.. press on the mouse and move it. By the way what browser are you using?

Comment: Still no exception.  I'm using Mozilla Firefox on Linux.

Comment: I am using google chrome on Windows, check the image attached with the post for further understanding of my situation.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is exactly the same and I only get this error when I click&hold the mouse over the map and start dragging it. It doesn't happen with the zoom or clicks inside the map or on the markers, only the drag/pan.
It is not a big deal to post the code since it is an Angular 2 Google Map sample available to all of us and without changing anything it happens. Of course I have tested the simplest config possible with typed in values and still happens. Here is the code anyway.
The template:

```
<h1>Sample Angular 2 Google Maps App</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <section widget class="widget">
        <p>Vivamus hendrerit arcu sed erat molestie vehicula....</p>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <div id="my-google-map">
        <sebm-google-map 
          [latitude]="lat"
          [longitude]="lng"
          [zoom]="zoom"
          [disableDefaultUI]="false"
          [zoomControl]="true">
          <sebm-google-map-marker 
            *ngFor="let m of markers; let i = index"
            (markerClick)="clickedMarker(m.label, i)"
            [latitude]="m.lat"
            [longitude]="m.lng"
            [label]="m.label"
            [markerDraggable]="false">
          </sebm-google-map-marker>
        </sebm-google-map>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the component:

```
import {Component, OnInit, AfterContentInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ElementRef, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {GOOGLE_MAPS_DIRECTIVES,
        GOOGLE_MAPS_PROVIDERS,
        provideLazyMapsAPILoaderConfig,
        GoogleMapsAPIWrapper} from 'angular2-google-maps/core';

// just an interface for type safety.
interface Marker {
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
  label?: string;
}
interface Bounds {
  sw: Marker;
  ne: Marker;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'myapp',
  template: require('./dashboard.html'),
  styles: ['sebm-google-map { height: 100% }', '#my-google-map { height: 600px;}'],
  directives: [
    GOOGLE_MAPS_DIRECTIVES
  ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  providers: [ GOOGLE_MAPS_PROVIDERS, provideLazyMapsAPILoaderConfig( {
    apiKey: '.... key ....'
  })],

})

export class Dashboard implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {
  // GoogleMaps related
  lat: number = 25.906032;
  lng: number = -80.255876;
  zoom: number = 12;
  latMin: number = 0;
  latMax: number = 0;
  lngMin: number = 0;
  lngMax: number = 0;
  $el: any;
  $mapDiv: any;
  mapPixelDimensions: any;
  bounds: Bounds;
  markers: Marker[] = [
    {
      lat: 25.801553,
      lng: -80.247964,
      label: '78'
    },{
      lat: 25.810098,
      lng: -80.240513,
      label: '66'
    },{
      lat: 25.822982,
      lng: -80.215868,
      label: '59'
    }
  ];

  constructor (
    el: ElementRef) {
    this.$el = jQuery(el.nativeElement);
    this.$mapDiv = this.$el.find('#my-google-map');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.recalculateMapPosition();
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.recalculateMapPosition();
  }

  recalculateMapPosition() {
    this.mapPixelDimensions = {
      height: this.$mapDiv.height(),
      width: this.$mapDiv.width()
    };
    for (var coord of this.markers) {
      if ( this.latMin == 0 ) { this.latMin = this.markers[0].lat; }
      if ( this.lngMax == 0 ) { this.lngMax = this.markers[0].lng; }
      // Test for minimum and maximum latitude
      if ( coord.lat < this.latMin ) { this.latMin = coord.lat; }
      if ( coord.lat > this.latMax ) { this.latMax = coord.lat; }
      // same for longitude
      if ( coord.lng < this.lngMin ) { this.lngMin = coord.lng; }
      if ( coord.lng > this.lngMax ) { this.lngMax = coord.lng; }
    }
    this.lat = this.latMin + Math.abs(this.latMax - this.latMin);
    this.lng = this.lngMin + Math.abs(this.lngMax - this.lngMin);
    this.bounds = {
      ne: {lat: this.latMax, lng: this.lngMax},
      sw: {lat: this.latMin, lng: this.lngMin}
    };
    this.zoom = this.getZoom(this.bounds, this.mapPixelDimensions.width);
    console.log('zoom: ', this.zoom);
  }

  clickedMarker(label: string, index: number) {
    console.log(`clicked the marker: ${label || index}`);
  }

  getZoom(bounds, dimm) {
    var GLOBE_WIDTH = 256; // a constant in Google's map projection
    var west = bounds.sw.lng;
    var east = bounds.ne.lng;
    var angle = east - west;
    if (angle < 0) {
      angle += 360;
    }
    var zoom = Math.round(Math.log(dimm * 360 / angle / GLOBE_WIDTH) / Math.LN2);
    return zoom - 2;
  }

}
```

I tested it with firefox 49.0.2 and it didn't happen.
It happened with 54.0.2840.71 (64-bit)
Not tested on Safari.